# Making a Python/GTK CheckMenuItem, when clicked, not close the menu

Tags: python, menu, gtk, pygtk

Using Python and PyGTK I've got a GtkMenu with various GtkCheckMenuItems in it.  When the user clicks one of the checkboxes the menu closes. I'd like for the user to be able to check a series of checkboxes without the menu closing each time.

I've looked at using the activate callback to show the menu but this doesn't seem to work.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see the problem here, the [`"activate"` signal](http://library.gnome.org/devel/pygtk/stable/class-gtkmenuitem.html#signal-gtkmenuitem--activate) does not allow you to return a boolean as to whether you wish the signal to propagate onwards. It sounds like you may need to poke around the [gtk.CheckMenuItem internals](http://library.gnome.org/devel/pygtk/stable/class-gtkcheckmenuitem.html), fire a signal that "reopens" the menu at the current position to be processed immediately after the `"activate"` signal has closed down the menu, or try the [mailing list](http://www.gtk.org/mailing-lists.html).

It's probably worth noting this is more of a GTK+ question than a PyGTK, as I believe the PyGTK API reflects the GTK+ one closely on this issue.

Comment: Thanks.  I'll go have more of a poke.

Comment: @davedavedave did you find a good way to achieve this?

Answer (score -1):

Try digging into source and it's documentation. I have found this to be the easiest way and best shortcut.